# How do I get two nav bars, one after the other, to be static and also snap to the top?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 nav bars that I want both the be at the top of the page initially but upon scrolling I want the first nav bar with the brand image to collapse away and the second nav bar with the list links to snap to the top of the page where the first nav bar initially was. Does anyone know how I can do this? Here's an image for reference: [image]

HTML:

```
<!----- Navbar ----->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-collapse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <img id="brand-image" alt="DEVO Logo" src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/D0.1/images/DEVOorig.png"/>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
      <li>
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search products..">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="product-search-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="info-head">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tobi's Site</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#section1">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">FAQ's</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Work With Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#section41">Drivers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section42">Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section43">In House</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#section5">T's & C's</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section5">Privacy Policy</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is javascript allowed?

Comment: If it works, by all means!

Comment: So, second question, do you want the first nav to snap instantly,or have a time to actually go down?

Comment: I haven't applied any of my CSS yet. Just bootstraps native commands. All I've just added 'collapse navbar-collapse' to the nav bars in HTML

Comment: I don't mind at this stage. I just want the branded (first) nav bar to disappear as you scroll and the second (links) navbar to be fixed to the top regardless of how far down you scroll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Bootstrap `affix` component to pin the 2nd navbar when the page is scrolled. Then add the CSS for the `affix` class to position the navbar when it's pinned to the top.

```
$('#nav2').affix({
      offset: {
        top: 50
      }
});
```

2 navbars example: http://codeply.com/go/hi6zhTU4h2